# C++11 multiple definitions of class function

Tags: c++, class, function, c++11, multiple-definition-error

RESOLVED: I'm a complete doofus. After pouring through all the files carefully and tracing back through our proprietary dependency file generator, it turns out that there were indeed rogue .cpp includes that had recently been added into the file system, and that was causing the issue.  Sorry, and thanks for all the help everyone! XD

I'm having a frustrating difficulty with an obscure bug I was hoping someone could help with.  Basically, I'm declaring a generic class in a header file like so:

```
//foo.h
#pragma once

class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    void random_function();
};
```

Note that I've declared pragma once to prevent multiple definitions, and all function prototypes are placed in class definition.  The corresponding class is defined like so:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

foo::foo() {
}

foo::~foo(){
}

void foo::random_function(){
//do stuff
}
```

This class gets used in quite a number of other files.  For example:

```
// bar.h
#include “foo.h”

class bar
{
  bar();
  ~bar();
  std::shared_ptr<foo> get_foo();
  std::shared_ptr<foo> my_foo;
};
```

But when I compile, I get the following error for each function member of the class definition:

```
bar.o: In function `foo:foo()':
dir/foo.cpp:80: multiple definition of `foo::foo()'
blah.o:dir/foo.cpp:80: first defined here
bar.o: In function `foo:foo()':
dir/foo.cpp:80: multiple definition of `foo::foo()'
blah.o:dir/foo.cpp:80: first defined here
```

Note how it appears to repeat the same 3-line error twice in a row.  This same error pattern is repeated for every constructor/destructor/function declaration.  Also note how it appears to be saying that the function foo() in foo.cpp is first defined in foo.cpp, which does'nt seem to make much sense.  But I just noticed, that it starts with bar.o and then says blah.o...?

Really scratching my head on this one, can't seem to decipher where the issue is coming from or where I should look.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Addendums:

- I can't post original code because it's from my work. I hope this example snippet is sufficient to at least give some direction as to where I should probably start looking, barring any issues with the code as it is currently set up.
- I'm not including any .cpp files elsewhere in the code.  I only include .h.
- Original code has semicolons at end of header file class declarations, just forgot to include in example posted here.  Updated to reflect that.
- Include of foo.h is consistent across all files (no accidental mixed casing).
- Other similarly defined classes are using this exact same pattern, but strangely are not generating the same error. :?
- To reiterate, I'm sure that I'm not #include'ing any .cpp files anywhere in my program, only header files are ever included elsewhere in the program.
- I am also sure that the constructor is declared in the header file as foo(); like in the above code example, and not foo(){}.
- Compiler supports pragma once (using g++).
- Fixed another typo in the above example not found in original code (quotation marks around header filename)
- The system I'm working on is actually quite large.  There are many includes and dependencies throughout the code (even some circular dependencies) and the use of some singletons that are passed about throughout the system.  The above example is a simplified representation of the issue I'm seeing at its most fundamental level, the above error I'm seeing is actually being generated for a number of new files I've been merging into the system (not just one).  Strangely, other files that I've defined after a similar fashion are not and have not hitherto generated this issue, which is why I'm confused that it appears to be causing problems now.

Comment: I think the class must finish with a semicolon...

Comment: Check to make sure you use the same casing throughout (e.g. not including `foo.h` and `Foo.H`.  I seem to remember there was a bug with `#pragma once` that didn't work if you included the file with a different casing.

Comment: The code looks ok. Did you try compiling the example? Does it compile correctly? Because if it does, then your example is not valid in this problem.

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious question, but does your compiler support `#pragma once`? All `#pragma` directives are implementation-defined.

Comment: This is a linker error; it has nothing to do with include guards or non-missing semicolons. Those would cause compiler errors. The problem that it's describing is that the constructor is defined in more than one source file. It's hard to tell from the error messages, but is it possible that "bar.h" in fact includes "foo.cpp" instead of "foo.h"?

Comment: Are you sure in your actual code, constructor is declared in foo.h as `foo();` and not `foo(){}`?

Comment: Hi, I'm sure that the I am not including .cpp files anywhere in my program, only header files.  I am also sure that the constructor is declared as foo(); in the header, and not foo(){}.

Comment: I'm also sure that the compiler supports pragma once (using g++).

Comment: You may have included `bar.o` or `bar.cpp` several times in the compilation/linking list of files. Or it could be something else. It is hard to debug stuff without seeing it. Try to reduce the problem to a small example you can post in its entirety.

Comment: Is a typo here #include foo.h must be #include "foo.h"

Comment: It sounds like for some reason, the file `bar.o` contains some machine code compiled from the file `foo.cpp`.  If you're sure all includes are correct, check the Makefile (or similar) command which generates `bar.o`, and try removing and rebuilding it.

Comment: " I'm declaring a generic class" -- sorry, but it sounds like the actual foo is a template. Is it so? Could you post the actual class, or, at least, its declaration and constructor's (or any other function's giving error) definition?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

//foo class and stuff

#endif
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but unfortunately there wasn't any change.

Comment: @Blood:  Yes, I made the change and converted all the pragma once calls to using #ifndef/#define with unique names as in the above example with #endif at the end of the file, and still no change.